# Generating UUID(unique ID) at joining points

Tags: qgis, qgis-3, qgis-plugins, widget, unique-id

I have road network (lines) and points (Address) . With the help of `closestSegmentWithContext function`, I join points to nearest lines in QGIS. Is there a way to to generate a unique ID at every joining point as the joining points are drawn manually in below image.

What I have researched so far:

- Found a possible solution  [here](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/73716/how-to-use-uuid-generator-in-qgis-2), but it didnt worked for joining points.
- I come accross a useful plugin "[AUTOFIELD](https://plugins.qgis.org/plugins/AutoFields/)" in anwer [here](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/245664/non-editable-date-uuid-is-not-saved-in-attribute-table), but this plugin is no more avaible in QGIS 3.XX

[image]

The code for joining line segements to nearest points is given below and shape files are available [here](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/245664/non-editable-date-uuid-is-not-saved-in-attribute-table):

```
roadlyr = QgsProject.instance().mapLayersByName('TR_ROAD')[0]
addrlyr = QgsProject.instance().mapLayersByName('ADDRESS')[0]

#List all features
adresses = [f for f in addrlyr.getFeatures()]
roads = [f for f in roadlyr.getFeatures()] 

#Create empty vector layer
vl = QgsVectorLayer("LineString?crs={}&index=yes".format(roadlyr.crs().authid()), "myLayer", "memory")
provider = vl.dataProvider()

for adress in adresses:
    a = min([road.geometry().closestSegmentWithContext(adress.geometry().asPoint()) for road in roads], key=lambda x: x[0]) #For each road find closest address
    gLine = QgsGeometry.fromPolyline([QgsPoint(adress.geometry().asPoint()), QgsPoint(a[1])])
    f = QgsFeature()
    f.setGeometry(gLine)
    provider.addFeature(f)

QgsProject.instance().addMapLayer(vl)
```

Comment: Use the `Default value` functionality that comes with QGIS 3 (that's why `AutoFields` was never migrated to QGIS 3): https://user-images.githubusercontent.com/652785/39675159-c9aa93aa-511c-11e8-8d6d-a4cc14cc5332.png   As expression, you can use something like `uuid()`. Make sure `Apply default value on update` is not checked, so that the `uuid()` is generated only when the feature is created.

Comment: @GermánCarrillo.Thank you for great suggestion. I able to generate UUID. The other difficulty is when i use  `closestSegmentWithContext`  function in above code in question to  join the points to nearest lines, the attribute table (myLayer) is empty as shown https://ibb.co/cDCjdhC . Is there a way to save all features of joining points like unique IDs, lengths of joining points etc in the attributr table. I am trying to generate UUID of every joing point inside attribute table.